# GraphView not showing line graph

Tags: java, arraylist, android-graphview

There is `xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:id="@+id/graph">

</com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView>
```

There is `java`:

```
LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_graph_weight);

    GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    for (int i = 0; i < FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.size(); i++) {
        series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(Integer.parseInt(FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmDay()), Integer.parseInt(FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmWeight())),
        });
        graph.addSeries(series);
    }
}
```

I know that data are collected from Array `weightDiaryList`, but line of graph not showing. If I replace x and y for, example, 5 and 10, all is ok.

If I using `series.setDrawDataPoints(true)`, point showing correctly.

**How can I fix it? How to display line for this Graph?**

Comment: Move ``graph.addSeries(series);`` out of the ``for``-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GraphView graph = findViewById(R.id.graph);
    for (int i = 0; i < FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.size(); i++) {
        series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[]{
                new DataPoint(Integer.parseInt(FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmDay()), Integer.parseInt(FragmentDiaryWeight.weightDiaryList.get(i).getmWeight())),
        });
        
    }
graph.addSeries(series);
```